# Trigonometric Inequality. $\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{C} \geq \frac{s}{r}$

Tags: geometry, inequality

> For any acute-angled triangle $ABC$ show that
>
> $$\tan{A}+\tan{B}+\tan{C} \geq \frac{s}{r},$$

where where $s$ and $r$ denote the semi-perimeter and the inradius, respectively.

Merci :)

Comment: Did you try to do something?

Comment: I don't know what to apply. I know only the relation : $$\tan{A}=\frac{\sin_{A}}{\cos{A}}, r\cdot R =\frac{abc}{4s}.$$ I need more help to solve geometric and trigonometric inequalities. thanks

Comment: $A+B+C=\pi\implies \tan A+\tan B+\tan C=\tan A\tan B\tan C$

Comment: there is a problem for me. How can I substitute $\displaystyle \frac{s}{r}$?

Comment: $\frac{a}{2R}=\sin A$ etc. and $\triangle=rs$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't know what means $\triangle$. Can you explain please. Thanks for information .

Comment: $\triangle$ conventionally represents area. Please refer to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inradius.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a$, $b$, and $c$ denote the sides of the corresponding triangle we have $s=s-a+s-b+s-c$. We also have $\frac{s-a}{r}=\cot\frac{A}{2}$ and similar identities for $b$ and $c$. So what we want to show is that $$ \tan A+\tan B+\tan C\geq \cot \frac{A}{2} +\cot \frac{B}{2} +\cot \frac{C}{2}. $$
This is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{\cos A} + \frac{1}{\cos B}+ \frac{1}{\cos C}\geq 6.$$ This inequality follows by application of the Jensen's inequality for the convex function $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ defined for $x\in\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.

Comment: how do you know that $\displaystyle \frac{s-a}{r}=cot\frac{A}{2}$? and how can I make the transition to the $\displaystyle \sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{\cos{A}}}$? thanks

Comment: If $E$ denotes the point where the incircle touches $AC$, then $AE=s-a$. Obviously, $\angle IAE = \frac{A}{2}$, $I$ being the incenter. So $\frac{s-a}{r}=\frac{AE}{IE}=\cot\frac{A}{2}$. For transition to $\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\cos A}$ you have to use a couple of trigonometric identities and some straightforward algebraic manipulation.

Comment: @S.B. Is there anyway one could do this without Jensen's inequality?